# api blocked in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

I am fetching data from https://api.rawg.io/api/games into my React project using Redux thunk I get back data normally when I get data from a specific id I get this error from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { gameDetailsURL, gameScreenshotURL } from "../api";

export const loadDetail = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  const detailData = await axios.get(gameDetailsURL(id));
  const screenShot = await axios.get(gameScreenshotURL(id));
  dispatch({
    type: "GET_DETAIL",
    payload: {
      detail: detailData.data,
      screen: screenShot.data,
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If the API is not configured with the correct CORS settings, and it is not your API, one of the solutions is to use a proxy that is configured to handle the request with the correct CORS headers.

It will look like this:

[image: cors diagram]

You can configure your own proxy or you can use a ready one like this (please note that the author of this proxy asks not to overuse is so if it is a big application you should set your own):

```
https://thingproxy.freeboard.io/fetch/https://api.rawg.io/api/games
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you call a server with a different domain name.

What is CORS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

A temporary solution is to use CORS blocker extensions on your browser

For example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en